# How to remove "Qt issued a fatal error: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display"?

Tags: export, warning-messages, linux

I'm using Mathematica 11.2 on Linux. At the end of my script, I'm adding an `Export` command to export my results into a pdf file. I'm receiving the error msg:

> Qt issued a fatal error: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
> :0.0 /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.2/Executables/Mathematica: line
> 150: 418313 Aborted                 "${MathematicaFE}" -topDirectory
> > "${TopDirectory}" "$@" $mesa

I tried to add:export USE_WOLFRAM_LD_LIBRARY_PATH=1 to bashrc or bash_profile but it didn't work.
Could someone please help me in solving this issue?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.